Asp.net core Web Api url parameters are not decoding in Linux server
Im sending a parameter string containing special characters by encoding it in a URL, as follows:
https://*******.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/users/john%5C45
It is not decoding in linux servers giving 404 error.
Please , assist me.
In middleware, tried below code for modifying context path url
`public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    try
    {
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var newRequest = request.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextFactory>()
                                  .Create(httpContext.Features);newRequest.Request.Path=PathString.FromUriComponent(WebUtility.UrlDecode(request.Path));
        await _next(newRequest);
    }`

still it is not working
Thanks.

You need to post some code as there are a myriad of possible reasons why this is not working.

Edited above ..

Hi @HemanthReddy, what if you decode the url by using code: Uri.UnescapeDataString(request.QueryString.Value) in the middleware?
